# How to always use single line comments in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, c++, visual-studio-2019

How do I force Visual Studio 2019 to use single line (`//`) comments instead of multi-line (`/* */`) comments when I press `CTRL+K`+`CTRL+C`?

Comment: You can also use Ctrl + / to comment out lines. Maybe that will work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is in Visual Studio 2019.

- To use a multi-line comment (`/*...*/`), select the block **without** the spaces
  before first selected line. See the following image where the four spaces before
  line number 5 are not selected.

[image: multi-line-comment-in-vs-2019]

- To use single line comment (`//...//`), select the whole block **with** the spaces
  of every line. See the following image:

[image: single-line-comment-in-vs-2019]

This is also valid for a single line. In the images, white spaces are set to be visible to understand easily.